# Python: ctypes _Pointer type hinting

Tags: python, ctypes, type-hinting

I am trying to build a function with type hinting which iterates over a C array/pointer as long a condition holds.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import _Pointer
from typing import TypeVar, Callable
T = TypeVar('T')

def foreach(array: _Pointer[T], cond: Callable[[T], bool]):
  i = 0
  v: T = array[i]
  while cond(v):
    yield v
    i += 1
    v = array[i]

# Example
c_array = ...                               # _Pointer[int]
for i in foreach(c_array, lambda i: i < 10):
  print(i)                                  # 'i' should be recognized as 'int', not 'Any'
```

The function works as intented and my IDE recognizes the types. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: type '_ctypes._Pointer' is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path-to-file>.py", line 234
    def foreach(array: _Pointer[T], cond: Callable[[T], bool]):
                       ~~~~~~~~^^^
```

So apperently '_Pointer' does not take an type during runtime but linters recognize this? How can I solve this issue?

When I use type aliases, only the name of the alias and not the acual type is displayed. And I dont want to tell python using type hints that the pointer is a e.g. list (`def foreach(array: list[T], ...)`), because this still returns Any and messes up linting and auto complete further down (and its misleading).

I use VS Code with the official Python package.

Comment: Add `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the module to stringify the annotations. This is failing because the class `ctypes._Pointer` does not have a `__class_getitem__` method, but the syntax `_Pointer[...]` is required for describing the generic types in the stub. The solution is to stringify the annotations so that there is no runtime execution of the type hint.

Comment: Another issue here is missing return type that should be `typing.Iterator[T]`, now you omit it so return type is `Any` for type checker. Weird that your IDE infers what it shouldn't infer. (yes, use annotations future-import for runtime, the error will go away)